# Sending Beacon Signals from a Web Browser

Tags: web, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'd like to send a beacon signal from my mobile web browser. Is there a way to broadcast BLE in a browser?
I checked the non-standard Bluetooth API, but there was no such function.

Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be support for this yet. There's an open request for this feature as can be seen here:-

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1043409
- https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/231

More information about web bluetooth support is found here:-

- [Start building with web bluetooth and progressive web apps](https://urish.medium.com/start-building-with-web-bluetooth-and-progressive-web-apps-6534835959a6)
- [Web bluetooth demos](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/demos)
- [Web bluetooth sample code](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/index.html)